# State is undefined inside of vuex action

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I can see from the Vue-DevTools that the playlist state is populated, but when I destructure the state off of the context object in my action, state is undefined...

Here is the relevant code:

```
import PlaylistService from './api/PlaylistService'

export const state = {
  playlist: {},
  oldTitle: '',
  oldDescription: ''
}
export const actions = {
  async edit({ commit, state }, payload) {
    try {
      console.log(state) // **undefined?!?!**
      const updated = await PlaylistService.update(state.playlist.guid, {
        title: payload.title,
        description: payload.description
      })
      commit('edit', updated)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  openEdit(state, payload) {
    state.playlist = payload
    state.oldTitle = payload.title
    state.oldDescription = payload.description
  },
  edit(state, payload) {
    state.playlist = payload
  },
  cancelEdit(state) {
    state.playlist.title = state.oldTitle
    state.playlist.description = state.oldDescription
  }
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

Here is the Vuex state tree from the dev tools:
[image]

And then I click a save button to do a patch request, and the `console.log(state)` in the above action gives undefined.

I don't know how to fix that. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I guess, the reason is being the `export` with the state. you do not need to write `export` for each when you export it in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Remove `export` from `state`, `actions` & `mutation` as you're already exporting them in the end with `export default`.

```
const state = {
  playlist: {},
  oldTitle: '',
  oldDescription: ''
}

const actions = {
  async edit({ commit, state }, payload) {
    try {
      console.log(state) // **undefined?!?!**
      const updated = await PlaylistService.update(state.playlist.guid, {
        title: payload.title,
        description: payload.description
      })
      commit('edit', updated)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
}

const mutations = {
  openEdit(state, payload) {
    state.playlist = payload
    state.oldTitle = payload.title
    state.oldDescription = payload.description
  },
  edit(state, payload) {
    state.playlist = payload
  },
  cancelEdit(state) {
    state.playlist.title = state.oldTitle
    state.playlist.description = state.oldDescription
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I export these individually because I am made to unit test them individually. The problem turned out to be in the PlaylistService itself. I wasn't adding the guid to the endpoint I was trying to hit. I have no idea why the `console.log(state)` returned undefined, but the code IS working now...